# Sum not being calculated properly

Tags: javascript, html

The program should do the following: The user should input numbers on the input field on the right and should click compute. The value will be pushed in the array. This will be done X times. At this moment X is hardcoded to 5 but that is not the problem.

The problem is that after the last number is pushed in the array, the sum of the array will be calculated and put out on the webpage. The visualisation isn't a problem and I am pretty sure that the calculations are correct. I think that the problem is how the input is read or inputet in the array. I might be wrong about this though.

One last thing, the function in which everything is calculated is compute1.
EDIT: the actual error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

This is the entire source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<title>Asd</title>
    <style>
        .btn{
            width : 30px;
        }
    .btn2{
            width : 100px;
            height : 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<center>    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Number of elements:</td><td><input type="number" id="textField" class="btn"></input></td>
            <td>Please enter a number.</td> <td><input type="number" id="textFiledInp" class="btn"></input></td>        
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="btn2" onclick="compute1()" >compute</button>
    <p id="output"></p>
</center>
</body>
<script>
//var eleNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("textField"));
var eleNum = 5;
var arr = new Array;
function compute1()
{
    console.log("hi");
    if(eleNum > 0)
    {
        eleNum--;
        arr.push(parseInt(document.getElementById("textFieldInp").value));
        console.log(arr[arr.length-1]);
    }
    else{
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.size; i++)
        {
            sum+= arr[i];
        }
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = sum;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `console.log(arr[arr.length-1);` <-- you're missing a `]` here. Typo?

Comment: Silly me, I have posted a bit older version. The real problem appears once this one is fixed. it is : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: @jsve, that is not the purpose of the code, a for loop would change everything

Comment: You have a typo. Change `id="textFiledInp"` to `id="textFieldInp"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the typos in your HTML, you should change the code to this:

```
var eleNum = 5;
var arr = []; //see explanation

function compute1(value) {
    console.log("hi");
    if (eleNum > 0) {
        eleNum--;
        arr.push(parseInt(document.getElementById("textFieldInp").value || 0, 10)); // see explanation
        console.log(arr[arr.length - 1]);
    } else {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = sum;
    }
}
```

You were using new Array; instead of new Array(), the better way is to use bracket notation. Or, in your case, you can define an array based on the length given by the user(with the input) or even using yours number of elements. It would be `new Array(eleNum)`.

Why `|| 0`? Because if the input is not defined by the user(value is null) then it sums up 0, otherwise you'll have NaN; remember to specify radix in `parseInt`, see nnnnnn's answer.

See a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBAUf/) of this.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed all the problems.

Comment: Anyway this script can be improved a lot, decreasing memory usage and increasing speed(we're talking of ms, but it is also a matter of code writing)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the `id` of your element:

```
id="textFiledInp"
```

...should be:

```
id="textFieldInp"
```

Otherwise `getElementById()` can't find the element and returns `null`, hence the error message you quote.

And your `for` loop is trying to use `arr.size` but it should be `arr.length`.

Presetting `eleNum` to `5` seems a bit strange, but I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do there so I'm not sure what to advise. I *suspect* you just need to move the commented out line inside your function and add `.value` (and uncomment it):

```
eleNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("textField").value, 10);
```

And also, never use `parseInt()` without specifying the radix in the second parameter. This is particularly important for user-entered data. (Because otherwise the browser may interpret a value with a leading 0 as octal, and a leading 0x as hexadecimal.)

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong ID of input:

```
<td>Please enter a number.</td> <td><input type="number" **id="textFiledInp"** class="btn"></input></td>
```

and you try to get element of id "textFieldInp":

```
document.getElementById("textFieldInp").value);
```

Change `id="textFiledInp"` to `id="textFieldInp"` and it should work.

And `size` is not correct property of javascript array. You should use `length` property in your loop.

If you want to push in `arr` the amount of numbers you've declared you should write something like this (I don't know if this is what you want):

```
    function compute1()
{
    console.log("hi");
    if(eleNum > 0)
    {
        eleNum--;
        arr.push(parseInt(document.getElementById("textFieldInp").value));
        console.log(arr[arr.length-1]);
    }
    else{
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            sum+= arr[i];
        }
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the next in the series of errors. It still doesn't show the correct input though.

Comment: The last update, it is not true. That way you take only one input from the user and then multiply it by 5, which is eleNum. The script wants to sum up 5 **different** numbers provided by the user.

Comment: as I stated: I didn't really know what he wanted to do eventually so it was only suggestion that he could use it or not. It's quite unfair that you've taken all stars for answer usefulness

Comment: Ok, now I see the point of gathering every single value. Description was a little blurry or maybe I'm a little bit sleepy. My apologize.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your calculations are correct, but you're missing a bracket `console.log(arr[arr.length-1)`

It should be:

```
        console.log(arr[arr.length-1]);
```